# Update count of union

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, union

I have this query which is throwing a compilation error at the last ')'. The intellisense says 'Expected AS, ID or QUOTED_ID'.

What I am trying to do is - find the distinct values from the union of a table select and a function select, then get the count and update the column of another table with that value.

```
UPDATE #referees
SET [TotalKeywordCount] = (select count(*) 
                           from (select Keyword 
                                 from [dbo].[RefereeFinderPersonKeyWord] P
                                 where P.p_id=#referees.p_id

                                 union 

                                 SELECT ltrim(rtrim(replace(Data, '''', ''))) 
                                 from [SplitOne] (@keywords, ',')))
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a name to the nested query that you use in the FROM of the query that pulls out the value for [TotalKeywordCount]. Below you have the code that assigns to it the name *subquery*:

```
UPDATE #referees
SET [TotalKeywordCount] = (select count(*) from (
        select Keyword from [dbo].[RefereeFinderPersonKeyWord] P where P.p_id=#referees.p_id
        union 
        SELECT ltrim(rtrim(replace(Data, '''', ''))) from [SplitOne] (@keywords, ',')) subquery )
```